# PHP document root for subfolder

Tags: php

I know how to play with `__DIR__` or `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` in `PHP`. it works well if files or folders are in root server directory for example `inetpub`. But my question is how to operate in subfolder directory? Example

```
inetpub->subfolder
         subfolder->classes
         subfolder->themes
         subfolder->index.php

define ('URL', '/');
<a href='. URL . 'logout.php >LogOut</a>
```

Script jumps into inetpub/logout.php should be my subfolder->logout.php

Comment: subfolder syntax is `../` (one step down) - `../../` (2 steps down) etc. You're just going straight back to the root here. You also add the (sub) folder to what you have now from the root.

Comment: So if i working with virtual directories (IIS all my website is virtual directory)  i need to create something like define ('URL', '../');

Comment: you could give that a whirl, sure. But I'd just go to the root and add the subfolder... in a way. But that's up to you.

Comment: What does `dirname( __FILE__ );` give you as result?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden - `dirname(__FILE__)` will give the same as `__DIR__`. Perhaps you meant `dirname(__DIR__)`?

Comment: yes that give all route c:/etc/etc

Comment: `define('BASE', '/subfolder')` will do for public web paths.  I'll leave it to you whether you want to include a trailing slash or not.